# How to show a tooltip with info from several data points that have the same x and y on google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

So basically I have data that looks like

```
['x', 'y', 'name']
```

that I am showing on a Scatter Chart.

I want the name to appear in the tooltip when hovering the data point, so what I did is have something like

```
data.addColumn('number', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'y');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
```

and then

```
data.addRows([x, y, name])
```

My issue is that it is possible that my data has several entries have the same x and y. And when that happens, a single data point is shown on the graph with the tooltip of the last name in the rows. I would like it to be a concatenation of the several names.

Any way to tweak the options to achieve this? Or am I doomed to build my own logic to handle it? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following option...

```
aggregationTarget: 'category'
```

> `aggregationTarget` - `'category'`: Group selected data by x-value.

---

**EDIT**

another option is to use a data view with a calculated column for the tooltip role.

the calculated column has a `calc` function that runs for every row.
here, find the x, y values for the current row,
then check the data table for other rows with matching x, y values,
and concatenate the names.

see following snippet...

```
// create data table
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'y');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});

// add rows
data.addRows([[x, y, name]]);

// create data view
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

// set columns on data view
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    // get x, y for current row
    var x = dt.getValue(row, 0);
    var y = dt.getValue(row, 1);
    var name = '';

    // find rows with matching x, y
    for (var i = 0; i < dt.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      var testX = dt.getValue(i, 0);
      var testY = dt.getValue(i, 1);
      if ((x === testX) && (y === testY)) {
        // concat name
        if (name !== '') {
          name += ', ';
        }
        name += dt.getValue(i, 2);
      }
    }

    return name;
  },
  role: 'tooltip',
  type: 'string'
}]);

// draw chart with view
chart.draw(view, options);
```

Comment: wasn't sure if option would work with a custom tooltip column, see __EDIT__ above...

Comment: This worked! Thanks mate :) Little question - what's the reasoning behind creating a datatable then convert it to a dataview?

Comment: creating the data view is the only way to have a calculated column, and we must have a data table to create a data view from...